# __new__ = TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, class, object, pygame

I wanted my class to be able to create objects by itself, and I saw this was possible with the '**new**', but apparently it's not working since I get this error  :

**TypeError**: *object() takes no parameters*

So there is the class I'm working with, I do post all of it in case it may come from another part of the code.

```
class Planete:

    def __new__(cls, rayon, periode, envergure,look):


        print("test __new__ of the class {}".format(cls))

        return object.__new__(cls, rayon, periode, envergure,look)

    def __init__(self,rayon,periode,envergure,look):

        self.rayon = rayon
        self.periode = periode
        #self.couleur = couleur
        self.envergure = envergure
        self.omega = (2*math.pi)/self.periode
        self.i = 0

        self.look = pygame.transform.rotozoom(look,0,self.envergure)

        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (0, 0))

        #self.surf = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)

    def tourner(self) :

        self.x = self.rayon*math.cos(self.omega*self.i)
        self.x2 = int(self.x)+600
        self.y = self.rayon*math.sin(self.omega*self.i)
        self.y2 = int(self.y)+300
        self.i = self.i + 1

        self.rect = pygame.Rect((self.x2, self.y2), (50, 50))

    def dessiner(self):
        #pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay,(self.couleur),((self.x2, self.y2)), self.envergure)
        #gameDisplay.blit(self.surf,self)
        gameDisplay.blit(self.look,(self.x2, self.y2))
```

Comment: Use ____new____ when you need to control the creation of a new instance. Use ____nit____ when you need to control initialization of a new instance.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need for you to define `__new__` here. Why have you done so?

Comment: How is that error message not clear?

Comment: Please edit your source code, so that it becomes a complete example that can reproduce the error. (Hint: removing PyGame related lines, adding `import math`, adding a line that leads to `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says: `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

In your `__new__` method, you call `object.__new__(cls, rayon, periode, envergure,look)` which is (with respect with the `cls` parameter) what would be called for `object(rayon, periode, envergure, look)`.

The direct fix is to replace that line with :

```
    return object.__new__(cls)
```

But anyway, as you have been said in comment, you have no real reason to use `__new__` here: extract from the Python Language Reference:

> **new**() is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation.

As your `Planete` class is not an immutable type, and as you use `__init__` for its customization, you should not use `__new__` at all.